# Pytorchを利用したNNモデルで中間層の値を抽出したいと考えています．

Tags: python, pytorch

Python初学者です．Pytorchを利用したCNNモデルで中間層の値を抽出したいです．Sequential()で作成しているのですが，全結合層の値を抽出する為に，各レイヤーにアクセスしたいと考えています．見易さを考慮して，CNNにおける畳み込み層と，全結合層を分割しているのですが，この状態でアクセスするには，どのようにプログラムすればよいのでしょうか．

print()

```
#ネットワークの定義
class net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net,self).__init__()
        #畳み込み層
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(#元々の入力12x12
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = 2, stride=1, padding=0),#filter16枚 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels =8, out_channels = 16, kernel_size = 2, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        #全結合層
        self.dence = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(16 * 10 * 10, 8),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(8, 16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(16, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 2),
        )
         
    #順伝播
    def forward(self,out):
         
        out = self.conv_layers(out)
        #Flatten
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        #全結合層
        out = self.dence(out)
        return out
     
    #畳み込み層の出力サイズのチェック
    def check_cnn_size(self, size_check):
        out = self.conv_layers(size_check)
         
        return out
```